Clarifying the definition of a geometrically connected variety
Let $\pi : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Vakil's Fundamentals of Algebraic Geometry ($\S$10.5.2, p. 291) defines a geometric fiber as the fiber over a $k$-point (a geometric point) of $Y$ for an algebraically closed field $k$. That is, the scheme
$$
X \times_{Y} \operatorname{Spec} k
$$
He then states the following Proposition 10.5.10 (p. 295)

Suppose $k$ is separably closed, and $A$ is a $k$-algebra with $\operatorname{Spec} A$ connected. Then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is geometrically connected over $k$.

The first couple of sentences of the proof is making me think I have misunderstood something. He says

We wish to show $\operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_{k} K$ is connected for any field extension $K/k$. It suffices to assume that $K$ is algebraically closed (as $\operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_{k}\bar{K} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_{k} K$ is surjective).

Don't we wish to check only those extensions $K/k$ for $K$ algebraically closed by definition? Why do we wish to check it for any field extension? The fact he then gives a brief justification for why it suffices to check only the algebraically closed case in the next sentence makes me think I have misunderstood, because I thought that was precisely the thing we wanted to check.
Adding to my suspicion I have misunderstood is the definition of geometrically connected given in the Stacks Project 0362.
Am I just reading too much into the wording, or have I misunderstood the definition?

Which version of Vakil's text are you using here, and can you add the detailed reference to the proof (e.g. "Theorem 18.2.4")? Vakil has put out a number of different versions of his text over the years, so it's good to be precise about what portion of which version you're referencing.

@KReiser sorry about that, I've included those references now.

Thank you for adding those references, this made writing an answer much easier! One further tip - $\operatorname{Spec} A$ produces $\operatorname{Spec} A$, which looks a little nicer than how you were doing it. You might want to keep this in mind for the future.

The thing that's going on here is that the following are all equivalent and all equally good to take as a definition for "$\operatorname{Spec} A$ is geometrically connected":

$\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes_k K$ is connected for any field extension $K/k$
$\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes_k K$ is connected for any algebraically closed field extension $K/k$
$\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes_k K$ is connected for $K=\overline{k}$.

The version of Vakil's text you're working off of seems to be written from the perspective of someone who's kind of moving between these definitions. The proof of 10.5.10 is working off of version 1 of the definition, while the statement is working off of version 2. (The Stacks Project link that you've included is entirely version 2.)
It's instructive to note how this has changed in the current (2024-09-08) version:

Proposition 10.5.10. Suppose $k$ is separably closed, and $A$ is a $k$-algebra with $\operatorname{Spec} A$ connected. Then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is geometrically connected over $k$. More generally, for any field extension $K/k$, $\operatorname{Spec} A\otimes_k K$ is connected.

Here Vakil has fully committed to version 2 of the definition in both parts of the text you're looking at. I think this was just a growing pain of the text - easy to have when you've spent 14+ years writing an 800+ page book.

I'm really sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, a few urgent things came up. This answer is really great and I've accepted it now. Thank you again :)
